# Trying to add a custom meta box to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a custom meta box to a wordpress page which stores a value in a custom field. It is not working. The meta box is displayed but when you press update the value entered ito the text box is lost and nothing is written to the wp_postmeta table (no _c3m_sponsor_ur meta_key is created)

I have adapted this from an example online. I also tried adding a die statement to see if the save post is even called but nothing dies. I also dont understand why the add_post_meta isn't being created for the page

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'c3m_sponsor_meta' );
        function c3m_sponsor_meta() {
                add_meta_box( 'c3m_meta', 'Sponsor URL Metabox', 'c3m_sponsor_url_meta', 'page', 'side', 'high' );
                }

            function c3m_sponsor_url_meta( $post ) {
                $c3m_sponsor_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_c3m_sponsor_url', true);
                if (!isset($c3m_sponsor_url))
                    add_post_meta($post->ID, '_c3m_sponsor_url', '', false);
                echo 'Please enter the sponsors website link below';
                ?>
                <input type="text" name="c3m_sponsor_url" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $c3m_sponsor_url ); ?>" />
                <?php
        }

add_action( 'save_post', 'c3m_save_project_meta' );

        function c3m_save_project_meta( $post_ID ) {
            die('here');
            global $post;
            if( $post->post_type == "page" ) {
                if (isset( $_POST ) ) {
                    update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_c3m_sponsor_url', strip_tags( $_POST['c3m_sponsor_url'] ) );
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help in fixing this is muh appreciated
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This may be help you:--

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'c3m_save_project_meta' );

function c3m_save_project_meta( $post_ID ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] )
    {
        if (isset( $_POST ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_c3m_sponsor_url', strip_tags( $_POST['c3m_sponsor_url'] ) );
        }
    }
}
```

## Edited:-


You can simply use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) plugin instead of using code. This plugin much helpful for custom meta fields.

Comment: Thanks but that didnt fix it. Why isnt the die being called or the custom field created when the meta box is first made? Thanks again for answering

Comment: your custom field is created because you added `add_post_meta` in display function...

Comment: Are you testing in page ??? because this process only update when you update or create `page`. See this condition `'page' == $_POST['post_type'] `.

Comment: Hi it definitely isnt created as it isnt in the database. After I update a page there is no postmeta with the key _c3m_sponsor_url for the current page or any page at all. And yes I am working on pages not posts. However it could be a faulty theme as the page meta fields arent working either. They dont hold 'retain' their values in the text fields when you save the page. I havent checked the database for those